# decentralized load balancing via UDP

Tags: networking, load, udp, cloud, load-balancing

I am trying to implement some decentralized load balancing and resource management using the following scenario:

- Each server sends out a UDP broadcast or multicast on a regular
  interval (e.g. every minute or 30 seconds), to let other servers nearby know
  the services that it is offering along with its health or load (e.g. cpu %, or memory
  usage, or network traffic   etc).
- Servers that have resources available to aid the overloaded servers
  could add additional services to its broadcasts/multicasts, thus reducing
  the load to the overloaded servers.

Would the extra overhead of the UDP traffic slow down performance in an already busy network?  Would a less redundant and more centralized approach be better?

I'm intending on using this for more than just traditional load balancing (e.g. to spin up new cloud servers when necessary).

Another variation would be to only broadcast / multicast when a certain load threshold is reached.

Any advice or other options/suggestions would be appreciated, especially regarding the impact on the underlying network and related devices etc.

Answer (score 1):

A small UDP packet with a server's current usage level isn't going to bring down a network, even one that's already busy. TCP is better at doing that, due to lost packets causing retransmits, thus creating even more traffic, but even then, this is won't be a problem for a couple of reasons.

First, your client traffic might arrive over a different network than the one your servers use to talk to each other. You might decide to create a heartbeat LAN, if you will.

Even if all the traffic resides on the same network, the client traffic will have been throttled by your WAN capacity which is always less than your LAN capacity. Meaning you will have LAN capacity to spare (unless something else is introducing traffic to your local network).

I think having load balancing in a decentralised model is interesting, but would pose a number of challenges, In fact whether it is possible, let alone advisable depend on the application you are trying to load balance...

I assume you know how normal load balancing works. Trying to do this without first understanding what it's replacing means you'll really struggle.

So as a first pass, the crux of this is having an application that can send it's client to another server. The broadcast you describe would allow a server to know if there were other servers it could redirect the client too, if certain thresholds were met.

As you say, if a server is really being hammered, it may not be in a position to process the packets it's receiving. In an ideal state, the server would pass work over to another server before it reached that limit, but then you have a choice, do you want the server to start refusing connections before it becomes 100% utilised? The down side of that is, you are never using your hardware to its fullest and you could get to a point where all of your servers are turning away users, while you still have cpu cycles left to use. Keep in mind, even with IaaS, like Amazon's AWS, there is a spin up time, a sudden jump in user requests are not an uncommon occurrence.

The other big challenge you will have is with fault tolerance.

Firstly, if a server goes dark with live clients, who do they contact, the last server they were speaking to (assuming there was one)? What if the reason the client left that server was because it was overloaded? Maybe he could go to his old server with a very light weight "Give me a new resource" request. If the old server's load has dropped, it can specify itself, if it hasn't, it can push it to someone else. Keep in mind though, that while all this is happening, the user isn't getting the service they arrived for.

The second aspect of fault tolerance is keeping the health status of the other servers accurate. You say you want your servers to broadcast or multicast they're health status, how many missed packets constitutes a down server? Networks drop packets all the time, it's how they work, but if you push a client to a duff server, only to have that client request time out and it come back to you, again, that's poor service for the client. If the client and server were on the same LAN, you'd not suffer much, but you add the kind of latency you get on the internet to the client/server communication, and your users could get bored quick.

The next issue you'll have to overcome is, just because a server is sending out it's status, doesn't mean the application is functioning properly. With centralised SLB, a test request is run against each server, which checks that all it's applications are functioning properly and takes servers out of the pool if they aren't. I don't think you'd want a situation where every server is testing the health of every other server. That's going to suck a lot of your resources up. I don't generally trust a server to deliver it's own health status, but I think if you wanted to make this work, you'd have to do that to some extent. The draw back though, is you are burning resources to run the query, answer them and then check the results. Those are all cycles that could be serving user requests.

The last issue I can think of is with the initial contact. If you use DNS round robin, you have to ensure that the servers on those addresses are healthy. You don't want a user having to wait for a timeout before they even got started. I'm not sure that writing a list of addresses or DNS host names into your client will help much either. The client will still  works it's way down a list, all the while, not doing what they arrived for.

It's been interesting thinking all this through and I hope it's been of some help. However the question I'm coming to is, what are you trying to achieve by decentralising your load balancing? There are probably solutions to all the problems I've raised, but without knowing your goal, it's hard to say if there isn't a much easier solution.

Still, hope this helps,
Alex

Comment: A lot of good content in there!  I came here researching headless round-robin algorithms and this question nearly perfectly mimicked my own.